# How to apply a macro for every single matching pattern

Tags: macro, repeated-commands

Macros can be repeated for every line matching a pattern with the global command as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390174/in-vim-how-do-i-apply-a-macro-to-a-set-of-lines).

This applies to every single line, but is it possible to do it for every single match? so if I save in a macro `ysiw"` (yank surround in word ") I repeat it for every matching regex, for example: `match1\|match2`
So that:

```
match1 nomatch match2
```

would become

```
"match1" nomatch "match2"
```

Comment: Aside: my mnemonic for `ys` is « you surround »

Comment: @d-ben-knoble. I like that. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 6):

Another way that also works across files is to use [:h :vimgrep](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Avimgrep) with `g` flag:

```
            Without the 'g' flag each line is added only once.
            With 'g' every match is added.
```

The workflow is:

- Init your search pattern with `/your pattern`, record your macro in `q`.
- Find all matching in your interested files:

```
    vimgrep //g  **/*.cpp **/*.h
```

- Reverse quickfix result with this command:

```
    command! ReverseQuickFixList call setqflist(reverse(getqflist()))
```

This step is necessary, as there might be multiple matches in a line, the second matching position might be invalidated after you apply your macro on the 1st matching. You need to do this in reverse order, but there has no `creversedo`.

- Apply your macro

```
    cdo norm! @q
```

Note that [:h :cdo](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acdo) doesn't stop if an error occured in the middle. If that's a problem, jump to 1st matching with `:cfirst`, record a another macro:

```
qp@q:cnext<cr>q
          ^-------carriage return
```

Repeat it with sufficient large number, it will stop at 1st error.

```
1000@p
```

Comment: If we go with the macro approach, another convenient way is to use CtrlSF plugin to go between files as we can directly edit the search buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Search for your pattern using `/`, then play your macro `@@`—you can record a new macro for this by doing

```
/pattern<CR>qqn@aq
```

Assuming `@a` holds your original macro. Then `@q` will jump to the next occurrence and play your macro. (For this case, you may need `qqn@anq`.)

In this case, you also do

```
:%substitute/pattern/"&"/g
```

Comment: But this will apply the macro to the next match, not to all of them right? I'm not sure if I understood it correctly. I'm looking for a way to apply the macro to every single (all of them) matching pattern at once

Comment: Yes—it applies to each match. You could hammer `@`, or or you could `@999q`, if you wanted to hit all. Unfortunately, global is just too linewise to use it here.

Comment: The proposed method doesn't work quite good. If you do `ysiw"` with vim fugitive it will position you in such a way that when you repeat it goes into the same word, so it keeps adding quotes to the same match.

Comment: surround, not fugitive, @Blasco, but point taken. See my substitute addendum. The first method works for most macros, but you could always add another `n` after `@a` for this case

Comment: You can play the macro multiple times if you do `n@@` too.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer is using vim-visual-multi.

First, select the pattern everywhere. To do so, use `\\/` and then `\\A` to select all. And then  `\\@` with the macro register.

In your case, you could have done `S"` instead of using the macro after `\\A`.

Comment: Unfortunately vim-visual-multi doesn't play quite well with plugins

Comment: Really, with what plugins? Maybe the keyboard mapping are similar